# How to subclass UIViewController with xib and add more view

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, subclass

I have a BaseViewController connected to it's .xib and want to subclass it with SubViewController in my storyboard to add more views. I already have do similar setup with UIView but it doesn't work for UIViewcontroller.
With no particular code, i only see SubViewController "screen" designed from storyboard. The BaseViewController xib is not loaded.

If i put below code in BaseViewController then i can see all the views from it but not from BaseViewController

```swift
 public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        var myCustomView = UINib(nibName: "BaseViewController", bundle: bundle).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as? BaseViewController

    }
```

With this code in BaseViewController i get "Can't add self as subview":

```swift
 let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        
        guard let view = bundle.loadNibNamed("BaseViewController", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView else {
            return
        }
        self.view.addSubview(view)

        view.frame = self.view.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

For the moment i can only have either BaseViewController or SubViewController views on screen but not both. The goal is to have BaseViewController xib setup behind the SubViewController views.

Can this be done with UIViewcontroller or does i do it the wrong way ?

Comment: Change the name of the subview let var (compiler may use view controller view property instead of view let var

Comment: I still have the "Can't add self as subview" error when i use  guard var viewCustom = bundle.load....

Comment: can you specify which code is for "BaseViewController" or which code is for "SubViewController" and also take the xib pics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing, it's just not possible to sublcass a UIViewcontroller and keep both the base code and add the new subclassed code to it.